# Post request from Android application failing + RestEasy + Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, resteasy

I am trying to send a POST request from my Android application and I get a MediaType conflict error or at least that's what I think. I want to send some data with the request and it should work but I think I am missing something. I am using Jackson and RestEasy as they come with the Wildfly server.

Here is my error log from my server:

```
15:18:20,790 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-6) Failed executing POST /posts/post: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: domains.Post of media type: application/octet-stream
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:67) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

Here is my postRequest() method:

```
public static void postRequest(String serviceUrl, Post post) {
        HttpURLConnection conn;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(serviceUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            mapper.writeValue(wr, post);

            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to url " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString());

        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is error log from my client:

```
04-06 09:18:18.634: I/System.out(1479): Sending 'POST' request to url http://10.0.2.2:8080/IslamicPostsWS/rest/posts/post
04-06 09:18:18.634: I/System.out(1479): Response Code: 500
04-06 09:18:18.665: W/System.err(1479): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:8080/IslamicPostsWS/rest/posts/post
04-06 09:18:18.755: W/System.err(1479):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
04-06 09:18:18.755: W/System.err(1479):     at services.JSONRequest.postRequest(JSONRequest.java:96)
04-06 09:18:18.755: W/System.err(1479):     at com.example.slidingmenu.AddPostFragment$RequestItemsServiceTask.doInBackground(AddPostFragment.java:65)
04-06 09:18:18.755: W/System.err(1479):     at com.example.slidingmenu.AddPostFragment$RequestItemsServiceTask.doInBackground(AddPostFragment.java:1)
04-06 09:18:18.827: W/System.err(1479):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-06 09:18:18.827: W/System.err(1479):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-06 09:18:18.835: W/System.err(1479):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-06 09:18:18.867: W/System.err(1479):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-06 09:18:18.935: W/System.err(1479):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-06 09:18:18.935: W/System.err(1479):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**EDIT** -- Server side code:

```
package api;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import database_wrappers.PostWrapper;
import domains.Post;

@Path("/posts")
public class PostAPI {
    PostWrapper postWrapper = new PostWrapper();

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        List<Post> posts = postWrapper.getPosts();  
        return posts;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes("application/json; charset-UTF-8")
    public Response insertPost(Post post) {
        postWrapper.insertPost(post);
        return Response.status(200).entity(post).build();
    }
}
```

And my PostWrapper:

```
public void insertPost(Post post) {

        try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context context = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

            dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/myJdbc");
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            String query = "INSERT INTO islamic_posts (post_title, post_content) VALUES" + "(?, ?)";
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, post.getPostTitle());
            stmt.setString(2, post.getPostContent());
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            con.close();

        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the server side code.

Comment: I posted it. I just want to say that the GET method works fine!

Comment: The GET works fine because it doesn't consume anything and produces `application/json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `@Produces("application/json; charset-UTF-8")` and `@Consumes("application/json; charset-UTF-8")` annotations to the class level or put both annotations in both methods. The error occurs because RESTEasy for default tries to parse the `Response` of `insertPost` to an `application/octet-stream` and does not have a `Provider` to do it.

Also, you should consider using a client library in your Android project like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It will make your code much cleaner.

Comment: thank you. :) it worked when I put both annotations to the class level.